# Pyspark - Save statsmodel trained models in GCS Buckets (or Driver)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, statsmodels

I am working with Pyspark to build regression models for each group in the data. To do so, I am using Pandas_UDF and am able to build the models successfully and generate the outputs and return them as a DataFrame.

At the same time, I wanted to save the model for future use but somehow I could not save it to the GCS Bucket.

If I simply save the model to the CWD, the models are saved but don't have access to the models saved locally in the worker nodes

Code used to save the model locally as follows:

```
model.save(l2_category+'.pickle')
```

The code used to save the model to the GCS bucket is as follows:

```
with open(os.path.join(gcs_path,l2_category+'.pkl'),'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(model,f)
```

But saving to GCS throws an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://darkstores-data-eng_stg/multi_sku_test/models/610a967aac6e434026bb7fa9.pkl'
```

Can someone help me with the best way to tackle this?